# discord options doesn't show and the message will be sent alone

Tags: python, class, discord, discord.py, nextcord

this is my code

```
        def __init__(self, no):
                super().__init__()
                self.r = []
                for numb in range(self.startnum,self.endnum):
                    self.r.append(discord.SelectOption(label=numb)) 
                discord.ui.select(
                    row = 0,
                    options = self.r)
        async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"{select.values[0]}")
```

the options doesn't appear but the message will be sent alone

to appear the numbers as options but this didn't happen and instead it only show me the message alone
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cHH1.png)

Comment: You're not doing anything with the select option after you declare it, why would it show up anywhere? It doesn't seem to be even assigned to anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using [`discord.ui.select`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.select) which is a decorator, and not [`discord.ui.Select`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.Select) which is the class.
Also [`discord.SelectOption`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=selectoption#discord.SelectOption) 'label' parameter requires string not integer, and you didn't send the select as a message, I think you have to use [`discord.ui.View`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=ui%20view#discord.ui.View).